# Ableton New User Question: Using Drum Kits

Tags: midi, ableton-live, midi-controller-drums

Is there a way to use a drum kit without programming it? For example, if I click on the 808Core Kit.adg in the Browser Content Pane, I get an audio preview. However, if I drag it to a MIDI track, I then have to program the beats myself. There may be a time when I just want  the basic beat I heard in the audio preview.  Is there a way to automatically use the same beat that was heard in the audio preview without having to program it in the MIDI Note Editor?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The preview drum loop is a pre-recorded audio clip inside the .ADG file.

How to use the example from ADG file?
https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?t=232901
(answer: not possible)

Extract pattern from Drum ADG file
https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?t=217638
(answer: not possible)